# Full page background bootstrap and hyper link

Tags: html, css

i built a web from 3 pictures with no content and when it goes mobile i use only one that is designed for mobile and with bootstrap full page background it looks very well.
the problem is when i try to make a hyper link that is kind of like image map but i think it's easier,the problem that it's not showing on mobile and i don't know why.
here is the code,please help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="full" lang="en">
<!-- Make sure the <html> tag is set to the .full CSS class. Change the background image in the full.css file. -->

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>The Big Picture - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/the-big-picture.css" usemap="#entermap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <img class="img-responsive myheader">


    <img class="img-responsive myfooter">
    <a href="waze://?ll=<35.1768493>,<32.9496625>&navigate=yes" title="" style="position: absolute; left: 13.47%; top: 91.75%; width: 73.47%; height: 6.49%; z-index: 2;"></a>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - The Big Picture HTML Template (http://startbootstrap.com)
 * Code licensed under the Apache License v2.0.
 * For details, see http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
 */

body {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    background: none;
}

.full {
  background: url("DSC_5703final.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
@media (max-width: 1000px){
    .full {
        background-size: cover;
         top: 0; 
         left: 0; 
  /* Preserve aspet ratio */
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%; }
}

.myheader{
    content:url("Untitled-1-01.png");
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.myfooter{
    content:url("Untitled-1-02.png");
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
    .full{
        content:url("bgad.jpg");
        width: 100%;
        background-size: contain;

    }
    .myfooter{
        content:url("");
    }
    .myheader{
        content:url("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you reffering to the thin strip at the bottom that links to waze? Are you saying it shows up on a regular browser but not in the mobile browser?

Comment: yes it wont show up on mobile

Comment: This may be due to the fact that you are using percentages for height

Comment: try putting height: 100% in the html, and body and all parents
like so:  `body, html {
height: 100%;
}`

Comment: this don't work either and it ruins the responsive mobile view.
it's like the hyper link to waze is a layer behind this so you can't even reach him

Comment: You can always force it to be on top with `z-index: 100` assuming there is nothing with a z-index higher than 100. I just picked 100 because its likely there is not.

Comment: Did it work or do you still have the problem?

Comment: i don't want it to be on the top i need it in the bottom

Comment: by on top, I meant on top layer. z-index determines which layer is on top of the other. If you set the z-index of one div to 1 and the other div to 2 for example, even if they are in exactly the same place, the div with a z-index of 2 will be over the one with z-index of 1. Thats how overlays are made.

Comment: Ok i understand thanks for the explanation but it still doesn't work,i gave the html class full a z-index of 1 and the link z-index 2 and i stil can't click on it

Comment: http://ssabin14.esy.es/
this is the code online

Comment: Your issue was that you were rewriting the entire page with an image using content property on html. See the answer I have provided below

Answer (score 1):

This is the rule that's causing you trouble.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
    .full{
        content:url("bgad.jpg");
        /* width: 100%; */
        /* background-size: contain; */
    }
```

You are using content to completely fill the the html with an image. z-index won't help you here because children inherit their parent's z-index. Since you are applying this rule to the html tag, there's nothing you can do to override it unless you make a separate container inside the html for your ad and assign it the `.full` class. Then make your map area have a higher z-index. then the new container can override the other container as long as they have a setting for `position` which is not static. i.e. relative, absolute

Remove `class="full"` from html. Instead make a new div or img with a `class="full"` at the top of the page. Then make sure to fix the z-index so it is higher than all the others.

For example you can try to modify your existing rule like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
    .full{
        content:url("bgad.jpg");
        /* width: 100%; */
        /* background-size: contain; */
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 10;
    }
```

and apply it to an img tag like so:

```
<img class="full"/>
```

Although, to be honest its always better to use text in your website. Since search engines don't index the images as text. So it won't be searchable in that way.

Find out more about z-index here: https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/